# Select2 allowclear not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

My select2 :

```
element.select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'blabla',
    data: {/*mydata*/}
});
```

Problem is that, than select2 don't clear option's list when new data added (manually or via ajax request).

On this, I decided to manualy clear options list, because select2 don't have same method to clear options list.

```
element.empty().trigger('change');
```

For showing new data I rebing the select2 to the same element.

It's well work, but after that select2 set first item of data as selected option and allowClear with placeholder don't working. What would I not do, select2 after manualy clear items set first item to selected option.

What I do wrong?

Comment: allowClear refers to the users action, not clearing it by code.

Comment: yes, I incorrectly formulated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add just default empty `option` that will allow the `placeholder` to work instead of clear all the select content :

```
element.html('<option></option>').trigger('change');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You save my life)) I dont understand, why select2 don't have standart method for this.